# Can't access apache and ssh from public ip but accesible via private ip thru vpn AWS ec2

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-vpc

My Server was working fine.
Today there was a sudden spike in the memory and i was not able to access my app.
After a while the memory loosen up a bit and the memory consumption returned to normal.
I've checked that apache is running (port 80) and ssh (22).
However when i try to access the server using public ip, whether it's the apache and ssh it's always connection time out.

The weird part is since the instance is on a vpc i can access the web application and ssh since i am connected to the vpn. They are working fine.

I am the IT guy that maintains the infra in which this instance is connected so the security groups are configured and also the iptables are empty so the only security settings are on the aws console security groups. All the other instances on this vpc are working fine and they are the same configuration with this problematic instance.

I am using openvpn access server which also resides on the vpc.

I am running out of options here. Need help from you guys.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Perform a packet capture and see if requests to the public IP are actually hitting the server. If they are, then perhaps there's something awry from the RAM contention and you'll need to restart the system

Comment: @EEAA i've already did a restart several times but still cannot connect.

Comment: Can you SSH in from an instance in the VPC using the private IP? Did you mean you're connected to a VPN, if so how is it set up? YOu really need to provide more information about the server, the VPN, and security groups to give better context.

Comment: @EEAA i have configured a vpc with a public subnet. The OpenVPN access server is on this subnet. i have 2 instances, the problematic one and an ok 1. I can ssh to the problematic instance using its private ip but not on its public ip. I can ssh to the ok instance using private and public ip. i have allowed all traffics on the security group to rule out the security group isses

Comment: I can ssh to the problematic instance through the vpn connection and using the private ip of the instance i can access the application on chrome. The firewall inside the instance is not the problem since i flushed it for the time being

Comment: When you say "restarted" did you perform a stop-start of the instance from the AWS console. That should cause it to move to new hardware. If you can  SSH to it from within your VPC, why don't you see if it can reach the Internet - for example - do "curl -vko /dev/null google.com" and see if that works?

Comment: I've rebooted the instance from the aws console. Yes i can ping google.com